# Перегрузка операций присваивания и сложения

Tags: c++, g++

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с перегрузкой операторов. Как к этому фрагменту кода написать перегрузку для оператора присваивания (=) и оператора сложения (+). Необходимо, чтобы корректно работала комментированная конструкция.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

class V
{
    private:
        int dimension;
        double* ptrdata = 0;

    public:
        V(int _dimension = 1): dimension(_dimension){}
        V(const V &obj)
            : dimension(obj.dimension){}
        ~V(){ delete [] ptrdata; }
        void Fill();
        void Show() const;
};

int main()
{
    V obj1(10);
    obj1.Fill();
    obj1.Show();
    V obj2(10);
    obj2.Fill();
    obj2.Show();
    V obj3(10);
    // obj3 = obj1 + obj2;
    // obj3.Show();
    return 0;
}

void V::Fill()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    ptrdata = new double [dimension];
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        ptrdata[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }

}

void V::Show() const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
        std::cout << ptrdata[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: А какова семантика сложения в данном случае? Что оно вообще должно делать?

Comment: Просто складывать значения по индексу. Например, вектор v1 [] = {1, 2, 3},  v2 [] = {4, 5, 6}. Ответом должно стать  v3 [] = {5,7,9}.

Comment: Ну тогда описывайте оператор присвоения, в котором создавайте и возвращайте новый объект класса V (не забудьте только проверить равенство `dimension` у слагаемых), а потом выполняйте присваивание. Только у вас все равно конструктор копирования (как и второй) не рабочий - размерность вы скопировали, а данные?... Вот примерно так надо и присваивать - скопировать dimension и перенести данные...

Comment: Обычно конструктор копирования выглядит так: const V& V::operator =(const V&obj)
{
    return *this;
}. Но как скопировать данные?

Comment: А так примерно выглядит конструктор для сложения (+): V V::operator +(V obj). Но вот что в теле писать пока не пойму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ладно, хоть это и очень непедагогично...

```
class V
{

    public:
        V(int dimension = 1):dimension(dimension)
        { 
            // Выделять память кто будет??
            ptrdata = new double[dimension];
        }
        V(const V &obj)
            : dimension(obj.dimension)
        {
            // Выделять память кто будет??
            ptrdata = new double[dimension];
            // Копируем данные
            for(int i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
                ptrdata[i] = obj.ptrdata[i];
        }
        ~V(){ delete [] ptrdata; }

        V& operator=(const V& obj)
        {
            // Присваивание самому себе
            if (this == &obj) return *this;
            // Если размер другой - надо создать новые данные
            if (dimension != obj.dimension)
            {
                delete[] ptrdata;
                dimension = obj.dimension;
                ptrdata = new double[dimension];
            }
            // Копирование
            for(int i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
                ptrdata[i] = obj.ptrdata[i];
            return *this;
        }

        V operator+(const V& obj) const
        {
            // Если размеры не совпадают - какое уж тут суммирование...
            assert(dimension == obj.dimension);
            V res(dimension);
            // Сами разберетесь, как суммируем?!
            for(int i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
                res.ptrdata[i] = ptrdata[i] + obj.ptrdata[i];
            return res;
        }

        void Fill();
        void Show() const;
    private:
        int dimension;
        double* ptrdata = 0;
};
```

Конечно, откровенно говоря, можно сделать и лучше. Добавить конструктор и присваивание перемещения, для присваивания использовать идиому копирования с обменом... Но все это потом, пока разберитесь с тем, что есть.

Да, и еще - вытащите `srand` в `main` - там же точность - секунда, вряд ли у вас супермедленная EC-1840, да и та заполняла бы быстрее :) - так что в вашем варианте `Fill` массивы будут одинаковыми.

Да, вдогонку: не выделяйте память в `Fill`! Для этого есть конструктор! А вы не можете ни без первоначального вызова `Fill` сложить, например, или вывести, ни сделать пару вызовов `Fill` без утечки памяти!

Comment: Все работает! Спасибо за помощь! Буду учиться расти в философии С++ :)